# How to combine email and appointment formatted text in Outlook 2007?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, outlook-2007

I have a training system which emails .vcs files to me, which I then have to import into Outlook through an annoying process - the text of the email is the majority of the interesting information.

Though I can fairly easily add the .vcs file to my calendar, I want to prepend all the text of the email to the meeting notice.

I can also easily replace all the text but I would like to combine them because I may accidentally overwrite important information.

I am using the WordEditor process to access the formatted text currently (this is the only way I found to be able to do this, if there are better ways, I am not tied to this). I was not able to really find any methods within the Outlook version of this to do what I am looking for.

```
Dim emailInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim apptInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim emailDoc As Word.Document
Dim apptDoc As Word.Document
'add the text of the email
Set apptInsp = AppointmentItem.GetInspector
Set emailInsp = myMail.GetInspector
Set emailDoc = emailInsp.WordEditor
Set apptDoc = apptInsp.WordEditor

'this will replace the appointment text with email text
apptDoc.Content.FormattedText = emailDoc.Content.FormattedText

'I want to do something like one of these but neither works
'apptDoc.Content.FormattedText = emailDoc.Content.FormattedText + apptDoc.Content.FormattedText
'apptDoc.Range(0).FormattedText = emailDoc.Content.FormattedText
```

- How do I combine the formatted text from an email and appointment within Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late ;)

```
apptDoc.Content.FormattedText = emailDoc.Content.FormattedText & apptDoc.Content.Format
```

Maybe it works if you use the "&", which you need to combine two strings...